# Symmetry in time dilation in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, time-dilation, observers

This question is related to this   [Time between two observer in special relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/543714/)

Suppose we have to observers, $A$ and $B$ so that when they are a distance $d=c\tau$ from each other measured by observer $A$,they agree to set both their clock to zero that is, $t_A=t_B=0$ for distance=$d$.
Now suppose that they are approaching, that is they both see each other with a speed $|v|$. Since $A$ sees $B$ moving his clock is faster than the clock of $B$. On the other hand  $B$ sees $A$ moving so his clock is faster than the clock of $A$.

My question is when they meet each other ,how their time will be related should we have $t'_A>t'_B$,$t'_A<t'_B$  or $t'_A=t'_B$?

Comment: If your ssumptions are symmetric, your conclusion must be symmetric.  That gets you the answer without calculating, though it might be instructive to go ahead and calculate anyway.

Comment: The question is incomplete. It does not specify in which frame d is measured.

Comment: Related : [How do I know which observer is running the time faster or slower?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/233649/how-do-i-know-which-observer-is-running-the-time-faster-or-slower/350359#350359).

Answer (score 0):

Neither will see the other observer's time as the same as the other observer does. When they reach points $d$ apart, as far as $A$ is concerned $t_A=0$ but $B$ at $t_B$ is still outside their light cone and they will see $B$ at an earlier time, say $t^A_B$, and vice versa. As they approach the time discrepancy $\Delta t = t_A - t^A_B$ reduces until, when they meet, $\Delta t = t_A - t^A_B = t_B - t^B_A = t_A = t_B = 0$

Answer (score 0):

I really am not an expert in the field, but I remember struggling on this for a while. "Since A sees B moving his clock is faster than the clock of B" is actually misleading.I believe the correct interpretation is that the readings of the ticks of clock A that A makes in his frame are faster compared to the tick readings of clock A made by B in his frame B. The same assertion can be made by interverting the points of view, and this is true whatever the relative positions of A and B, so there is no contradiction. It just means that the time perception of the same events (ticks of a given clock) are not the same in the two frames with a relative velocity.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between this and other questions to which it is related is that you have the observers approaching and say

> when they are a distance $d=c\tau$ from each other measured by observer $A$,they agree to set both their clock to zero that is, $t_A=t_B=0$

but this is a meaningless assigment. The twins have a different notion of when this is precisely because they define different reference frames. Therefore you should see the answers to the linked questions.

Answer (score -1):

These confusion arise because we separate spacetime in space +time. We should  think that spacetime is a four dimensional manifold

In Special relativity spacetime is the tuple $(\mathcal{R}^4, \mathcal{O}, \mathcal{A}^{\uparrow}, \nabla, \eta, T,)$,
where $\nabla$ is a  torsion free connection $\eta=(+---)$ a Lorentzian metric,$\mathcal{O}$ the standard topology,$\mathcal{A}^{\uparrow}$ an atlas and $T$  a time-orientation.

A $\textbf{clock}$ carried by a specific observer $(\gamma, e)$ will measure a $\textbf{time}$
$$
time := \int_{\tau_0}^{\tau_1} d\tau \sqrt{ \eta_{\lambda(\tau)}(v_{\lambda,\lambda(\tau)}, v_{\lambda,\lambda(\tau)}) }
\tag1$$
between the two $''\underline{events}''$
$$
\lambda(\tau_0) \quad \quad \quad \, \text{ "start the clock'' }
$$
and
$$
\lambda(\tau_1) \quad \quad \quad \, \text{ "stop the clock'' }
$$
Here  $v_{\lambda,\lambda(\tau)})$ is the tangent vector of the the curve $\lambda$ at the point $\lambda(\tau)$

Lets choose coordinates $(x_0=ct,x_1=x,x_2=y,x_3=z)$ such that the trajectory of observer $A$ in spacetime is given by
$$\lambda_A(\tau)=(c\tau,0,0,0)$$
and the trajectory of observer $B$ in spacetime is given by $$\lambda_B=(c\tau,d-v\tau,0,0)$$From these equation we see that $A$ and $B$ meet at $\tau= \frac{d}{v}$

In these  coordinates the metric is given by $$\eta=dt\otimes dt-dx\otimes dx-dy\otimes dy-dz\otimes dz \tag 2$$

and the tangents vectors are given by
$$v^A_{\lambda,\lambda(\tau)}=c \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \tag 3$$

$$v^B_{\lambda,\lambda(\tau)}=c \frac{\partial}{\partial t}-v\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \tag 4$$

so we have
$$n(v^A_{\lambda,\lambda(\tau)},v^A_{\lambda,\lambda(\tau)})=c^2 \tag2$$
$$n(v^B_{\lambda,\lambda(\tau)},v^B_{\lambda,\lambda(\tau)})=c^2-v^2 \tag3$$
than the time elapsed until their meeting for observer $A$ is
$$t_A=\frac{1}{c}\int_0^\frac{d}{v}\sqrt{c^2}=\frac{d}{v}$$

The time for $B$ is given by
$$t_B=\frac{1}{c}\int_0^\frac{d}{v}\sqrt{c^2-v^2}=\frac{1}{\gamma}\frac{d}{v}$$

Eq.1 is coordinate independent so  if we make the calculation from the perspective of $B$ we should obtain the same result.